# Is there a way to find out if a property or variable has been set?

Tags: c#, reflection, variables, properties

As per title, can I find out the history of a property or variable, in terms of whether it has been set or not?

Reason for this is I have some query classes, any properties that have not been set should not be included in the generated query.

Currently I am just trying to add a PropertyInfo instance (I need the name of the property, this is vital to the query generation due to mappings) to a list of properties which have been set in set{}. This is ugly though as it requires more code for what should be classes that only contain properties and no logic (i.e. no removal of stufffrom a list).

Is there something built-in I can use or a more elegant method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the properties nullable, e.g. of type `int?` instead of type `int`, so that their value is `null` if they haven't been set.

Comment: This won't give you anything since the fields in the DB could be null as well.

Comment: @Shimmy I may be wrong but I think that the use case is to a) set some properties in a struct b) use those property values to build a SELECT statement.

Comment: I don't believe the OP has decided to invent the EF anew. I think he probably wants to select the ID and a Name field at first for 'master' collection, then the rest of the fields for the 'details' collection.

Comment: Might also be that does it for undo/redo list, but then he would need the `INotifyPropertyChanging` and this will also not help him, read [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632384/propertychangingeventargs-class-should-provide-the-candidate-value) why.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this answer. I didn't know this feature existed *slaps forehead*. Yes I am using it to build a SELECT statement :) This will be changed in the future for performance reasons. Long story why this is being done.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're talking about dynamic entities, you could check for null using reflection but this won't tell you anything if the original value was null (or zero in case of numeric data-types).

But **best way** is to make it implement INotifyPropertyChanged and have a list of properties that have been materialized.

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> _MaterializedPropertiesInternal;
    private List<string> MaterializedPropertiesInternal
    {
        get
        {
            if (_MaterializedPropertiesInternal==null) 
                _MaterializedPropertiesInternal = new List<string>();
            return _MaterializedPropertiesInternal;
        }
    }

    private ReadOnlyCollection<string> _MaterializedProperties;
    public IEnumerable<string> MaterializedProperties
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_MaterializedProperties==null) _MaterializedProperties = 
              new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(MaterializedPropertiesInternal);
            return _MaterializedProperties;
        }
    }

    private int _MyProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return _MyProperty; }
        set
        {
            _MyProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, 
          new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        MaterializedPropertiesInternal.Add(propertyName);
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: +1 for `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That is what I was thinking.

Comment: "and have a list of properties that have been materialized." use a *Set* instead of list. If you change the same property multiple times, it is added to the list again (multiple entries), whiles it is not added again to the Set.(came across into this thread while I was looking for something else. So don't mind me...I'll move on ;-))